# Ito lemma for manifold semimartingales

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, stochastic-processes, smooth-manifolds, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm looking for a generalization of the usual Ito lemma to manifolds $M$, preferably not under the assumption that $M$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Unfortunately any reference I've found either assumes $M$ is a submanifold of Euclidean space.

Comment: Why is this assumption a problem, given that any manifold can be embedded in Euclidean space?

Comment: Oh I want M to be Riemannian, so I'm not sure if it can be embedded if it is not compact...
Regarless, I can't find a legible (due to super old terminiolody) text with this type of result.

Comment: Every smooth manifold, compact or not, can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Driver, Emery, Hsu?

Comment: You can find precise statements of the existence of an isometric embedding of any Riemannian manifold into Euclidean space in the book: Han, Qing; Hong, Jia-Xing (2006). Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs. 130. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society.

Comment: Nevertheless, embedding a Riemannian manifold is a violent act, like choosing a basis for a vector space, since there is no canonical choice. It is even worse than choosing a basis, since there is no algorithm, even if the Riemannian metric is explicitly expressed in coordinates.

Comment: @Nate I found something in the 1980s by Elworthy set on Hilbert manifolds but it seems to be missing some key assumptions I have seen in the stochastic calculus I Hilbert spaces

Comment: Also I found a result by Driver a Birkhauser book by Rao but the formulation depended on an embedding..so...

Comment: You might have a look at Michel Émery's monograph *Stochastic calculus in manifolds* <http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-75051-9>.